# Why does parenting handle bones differently than the Child of constraint?

Tags: bones, constraints, parent

When an object is parented to an armature's bone it's center is originated at the bones tip, which for some reason is called tail... (that part is never gonna make sense to me but whatever)

But when you use the Child of constraint it will be originated at the bone's root.

[image: derp]

Here's an image showing one bone, 2 icospheres, neither has been moved at all.

Icosphere.001 is parented to the bone, the panel on the right shows it's info.

Icosphere is Child of constrained to the same bone, shown on the left and in the center.
The only thing they share is the rotation and scale, but the location is obviously different, for whatever reason.

Why is this like that?